# sass: Building html5up.net template fails

Tags: css, html, sass

This is probably a noob question and can hopefully be answered easily. On [html5up.net](https://html5up.net/) you can download css templates that include the unprocessed sass source files. I'm trying to build the [Twenty](https://html5up.net/twenty) template using

```
sass sass/main.scss
```

and I get the error

> ```
> Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "     wide": expected ")", 
>   was ": '(max-width: ..." on line 16 of sass/main.scss
> ```

I'm using `Sass 3.2.12 (Media Mark)` on Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately, there are no build-instructions on the html5up page and I guess it is obvious for everyone else how to preprocess the `*.scss` files.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can create the css output from the scss files?

### Edit

Here is the `main.scss` up until line 22:

```
@import 'libs/vars';
@import 'libs/functions';
@import 'libs/mixins';
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900");
/*
    Twenty by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
*/

@import "libs/skel";

@include skel-breakpoints((
    wide: '(max-width: 1680px)',
    normal: '(max-width: 1280px)',
    narrow: '(max-width: 980px)',
    narrower: '(max-width: 840px)',
    mobile: '(max-width: 736px)'
));
```

Comment: Hard to say, given it's a paid theme and we don't have any useful source to go off. Show us the lines around line 16.

Comment: @ceejayoz Sorry, didn't think of that :) Fixed.

Comment: https://github.com/ajlkn/skel/issues/142 indicates some issues with `libsass` that version 3.3 fixes. Consider upgrading to Sass 3.3.

Comment: also cant find documentation. FYI command to watch all scss folders and generate to css would be `sass --watch sass:css`

Answer (score 1):

It seems upgrading to a newer `sass` indeed helps as suggested by @ceejayoz. Therefore, on Ubuntu 14.04 just remove the `ruby-sass` package if you have installed it

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby-sass
```

and then install it by using `gem` as described on the [official sass-lang page](http://sass-lang.com/install)

```
sudo su -c "gem install sass"
```

after that, the version of `sass` should be > 3.2

```
user@machine$ sass --version
Sass 3.4.22 (Selective Steve)
```